# How to install ml_finance-master in python 3.6

Tags: python, matplotlib

I download all the files of ml_finance-master from  https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance

Then I extract all the files into D:\Programing\Python\Scripts.

In the CMD I type, C:\Users\84334>D:\Programing\Python\Scripts\pip install mpl_finance.

However, it shows,

Collecting mpl_finance
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mpl_finance (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mpl_finance

I also tried in CMD, C:\Users\84334>D:\Programing\Python\Scripts\pip install mpl_finance-master

However,it shows,

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mpl_finance-master (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mpl_finance-master

I am totally new to python. Could anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github repo for this package contains `setup.py` file, which based on [setuptools](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html). According to documentation you can run terminal (cmd) in directory with `setup.py` file and write following:

```
python setup.py install
```

After that, installation should be performed.

Comment: Thanks so much! it helps a lot!